# How to send Date in REST API in POST method

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, localdate

I am trying to build RESTful web service  with Spring support. I am getting following exception when I am trying to send POST request.

Input:

```
POST    http://localhost:8080/InventoryDemo/item
```

In JSON Payload:

```
{"materialId":"ID02","materialName":"Material_2","materialCategory":"LIQUID","currency":"RUPEES","unitCostInCurrency":2200.0,"quantityLevel":1000,"quantityAtDate":"2016-04-11","warehouseName":"WareHouse_2"}
```

Exception:

```
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('2016-04-11'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@378ace07; line: 1, column: 146] (through reference chain: com.psl.inventory.model.InventorySystemModel["quantityAtDate"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('2016-04-11'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@378ace07; line: 1, column: 146] (through reference chain: com.psl.inventory.model.InventorySystemModel["quantityAtDate"])
```

This is my POST method from @RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createInventorySystemModel(@RequestBody InventorySystemModel inventorySystemModel,  UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        System.out.println("Creating InventorySystemModel " + inventorySystemModel.getMaterialName());

        if (inventorySystemService.isInventorySystemModelExist(inventorySystemModel)) {
            System.out.println("A InventorySystemModel with name " + inventorySystemModel.getMaterialName() + " already exist");
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        inventorySystemService.saveInventoryItem(inventorySystemModel);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{materialId}").buildAndExpand(inventorySystemModel.getMaterialId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and this is my POJO class:

```
public class InventorySystemModel {

    private String materialId;
    private String materialName;
    private String materialCategory;
    private String currency;
    private double unitCostInCurrency;
    private int quantityLevel;
    private LocalDate quantityAtDate;
    private String warehouseName;

    public InventorySystemModel(){

    }
    public InventorySystemModel(String materialId, String materialName,
            String materialCategory, String currency,
            double unitCostInCurrency, int quantityLevel, LocalDate quantityAtDate,
            String warehouseName) {
        super();
        this.materialId = materialId;
        this.materialName = materialName;
        this.materialCategory = materialCategory;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.unitCostInCurrency = unitCostInCurrency;
        this.quantityLevel = quantityLevel;
        this.quantityAtDate = quantityAtDate;
        this.warehouseName = warehouseName;
    }

    public String getMaterialId() {
        return materialId;
    }
    public void setMaterialId(String materialId) {
        this.materialId = materialId;
    }
    public String getMaterialName() {
        return materialName;
    }
    public void setMaterialName(String materialName) {
        this.materialName = materialName;
    }
    public String getMaterialCategory() {
        return materialCategory;
    }
    public void setMaterialCategory(String materialCategory) {
        this.materialCategory = materialCategory;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public double getUnitCostInCurrency() {
        return unitCostInCurrency;
    }
    public void setUnitCostInCurrency(double unitCostInCurrency) {
        this.unitCostInCurrency = unitCostInCurrency;
    }
    public int getQuantityLevel() {
        return quantityLevel;
    }
    public void setQuantityLevel(int quantityLevel) {
        this.quantityLevel = quantityLevel;
    }
    public LocalDate getQuantityAtDate() {
        return quantityAtDate;
    }
    public void setQuantityAtDate(LocalDate quantityAtDate) {
        this.quantityAtDate = quantityAtDate;
    }
    public String getWarehouseName() {
        return warehouseName;
    }
    public void setWarehouseName(String warehouseName) {
        this.warehouseName = warehouseName;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((currency == null) ? 0 : currency.hashCode());
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((materialCategory == null) ? 0 : materialCategory.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((materialId == null) ? 0 : materialId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((materialName == null) ? 0 : materialName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((quantityAtDate == null) ? 0 : quantityAtDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + quantityLevel;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(unitCostInCurrency);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result
                + ((warehouseName == null) ? 0 : warehouseName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        InventorySystemModel other = (InventorySystemModel) obj;
        if (currency == null) {
            if (other.currency != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!currency.equals(other.currency))
            return false;
        if (materialCategory == null) {
            if (other.materialCategory != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!materialCategory.equals(other.materialCategory))
            return false;
        if (materialId == null) {
            if (other.materialId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!materialId.equals(other.materialId))
            return false;
        if (materialName == null) {
            if (other.materialName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!materialName.equals(other.materialName))
            return false;
        if (quantityAtDate == null) {
            if (other.quantityAtDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!quantityAtDate.equals(other.quantityAtDate))
            return false;
        if (quantityLevel != other.quantityLevel)
            return false;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(unitCostInCurrency) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.unitCostInCurrency))
            return false;
        if (warehouseName == null) {
            if (other.warehouseName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!warehouseName.equals(other.warehouseName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InventorySystemModel [materialId=" + materialId
                + ", materialName=" + materialName + ", materialCategory="
                + materialCategory + ", currency=" + currency
                + ", unitCostInCurrency=" + unitCostInCurrency
                + ", quantityLevel=" + quantityLevel + ", quantityAtDate="
                + quantityAtDate + ", warehouseName=" + warehouseName + "]";
    }
}
```

FYI: I did checked [this](https://blog.oio.de/2015/06/13/add-support-for-java-8-date-time-api-to-jackson-serialized-rest-web-services/) post but not getting clue like where exactly I need to do modification.

I am using Java 8 and Spring 4.2

Can some one please explain in detail like what exactly I need to do here.
**Also I want same date format when I will hit GET request.**

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have public void setQuantityAtDate(String quantityAtDate) and have a dateFormatter taking the string input and converting it to Date?

Comment: This question is more similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571587/deserializing-localdatetime-with-jackson-jsr310-module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your Custom [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) Deserializer. This Deserializer will be called when setter method for the [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) variable is called.

Steps as follows:

1. Define a Custom Deserializer

   ```
   public class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate>{

     @Override
     public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
           throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

         DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("required format");

         LocalDate localDate = null;
         localDate = LocalDate.parse(p.getText(), formatter);

         return localDate;
     }
   }
   ```

Note: Reference for [LocalDate.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) method.

2. Define @JsonDeserialize annotation above the variable

   ```
   @JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class)
   private LocalDate quantityAtDate;
   ```

For using @JsonDeserialize annotation import following:

> import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think we have to register this deserializer with objectmapper like mentioned here http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization.

Comment: @Barath Actually in my Spring MVC application I didn't register it., May be Spring is automatically doing that on finding the annotation.

Answer (score 6):

### The error

[`JsonMappingException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException.html) is an exception thrown by Jackson, a JSON parser for Java. It indicates fatal problems when mapping a JSON to a Java bean.

In this situation, looks like the string `2016-04-11` cannot be parsed to a `LocalDate` from Java 8.

### How to fix it

Jackson supports Java 8 date types, but the following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And then configure your `ObjectMapper`:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {  
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

By default, dates will be serialized in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. If you want to change the format, you can use [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html):

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM")
private LocalDate date;
```

No custom (de)serializers are required.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of **@JsonFormat** to define the date format

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

```
public class InventorySystemModel {

     private String materialId;
        private String materialName;
        private String materialCategory;
        private String currency;
        private double unitCostInCurrency;
        private int quantityLevel;
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date quantityAtDate;
        private String warehouseName;
//getters and setters
}
```

Request :

```
{
    "materialId": "ID02",
    "materialName": "Material_2",
    "materialCategory": "LIQUID",
    "currency": "RUPEES",
    "unitCostInCurrency": 2200.0,
    "quantityLevel": 1000,
    "quantityAtDate": "2016-04-11",
    "warehouseName": "WareHouse_2"
}
```

Response :

```
InventorySystemModel [materialId=ID02, materialName=Material_2, materialCategory=LIQUID, currency=RUPEES, unitCostInCurrency=2200.0, quantityLevel=1000, quantityAtDate=Mon Apr 11 05:30:00 IST 2016, warehouseName=WareHouse_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a deserializer for parsing the LocalDate.

Add Maven dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

If your restful service is parsing the bean directly, add the below

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;

@PostMapping(value = "/xyz")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
public  ResponseEntity <String> testMethod (@RequestBody Bean bean){
}
```

Else, add `deserializer` in the bean class.