# Post request and "The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource" error

Tags: java, spring, jackson, postman

I am using Postman and learning how to do a POST request to add a new `Item` to the cart and write it to the database. The `Java` code for the item is:

```java
public class Item  {    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate expired;
}
```

with getters and setters.

In `Spring` framework I have the next method:

```java
@PostMapping
public void add(@RequestBody Item newItem) {
    itemSer.addNewItem(newItem);
}
```

Using postman in the body part I selected `raw` -> `json`: (its the result of a `GET` request.)

```json
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "postman",
   "description": "postman",
   "expired": {
        "year": 1700,
        "month": "NOVEMBER",
        "monthValue": 11,
        "dayOfMonth": 21,
        "leapYear": false,
        "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 325,
        "era": "CE",
        "chronology": {
            "id": "ISO",
            "calendarType": "iso8601",
            "isoBased": true
        }
    }
}
```

Postman give me an `405` error but I have no idea why, I am using tomcat 9. Is there same problem also for the date format?

**EDIT:**

So the problem is only on the `LocalDate`, I have to format in a way that is readable by java with a Post request.
Snooping around I did find this solution: [How to send Date in REST API in POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668936/how-to-send-date-in-rest-api-in-post-method)

(if you are using maven)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

the add in the AppConfig di spring:

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {  
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());                
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return mapper;
}
```

and int the `Itmes` class over the `LocalDate` variable:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
```

the post is now just looks like the next:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "postman",
    "description": "postman",
    "expired": "2030-01-02"
}
```

I still have a question, reading this i did understand generally how it works, where can I find some other info on how this works? or if someone want to explain I am happy to listen.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention it, but it appears you're using `Spring` framework for working with `HTTP` and `Jackson` for `JSON` handling. `Spring` framework actually uses `Jackson` as its default implementation for parsing request and response bodies. `Spring` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-json.html):

> Spring Boot provides integration with three JSON mapping libraries:
>
> - Gson
> - Jackson
> - JSON-B
>
> Jackson is the preferred and default library.

It means that each time an `HTTP` request reaches your controller method, `Jackson` parses the raw `HTTP` body into an `Item` object:

```java
@PostMapping
public void add(@RequestBody Item newItem) {
    //newItem have already parsed from JSON by Jackson
    itemSer.addNewItem(newItem);
}
```

`Jackson` has a modular design, meaning that it can be extended with modules to provide additional functionality. A module is a collection of serializers, deserializers, and other components that extend Jackson's capabilities.
For example, the `JavaTimeModule` provides support for serializing and deserializing `Java 8` date and time classes, such as `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`.

To use a particular module in Jackson, you simply need to register it with an instance of the `ObjectMapper` class. This can be done with the `registerModule()` method, as shown in the example in your question.

Once registered with an `ObjectMapper`, a module's serializers and deserializers become available for parsing `HTTP` bodies and you can then use `Jackson` annotations like `@JsonFormat` to further customize the serialization and deserialization of specific classes and fields.

Before `Java 8`, Jackson supported `Java 6` and `7`, which did not have any built-in date and time classes. So, to handle dates and times, `Jackson` relied on external libraries, such as [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), or on custom serializers and deserializers that were written by the user.

---

- If you want to learn more about `Jackson`, you can read its official [comprehensive documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs).
- Here is a `jackson-modules-java8` [GitHub repository](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)
- Quite good [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384820/is-there-a-jackson-datatype-module-for-jdk8-java-time) is exists that explains how to connect `jackson-datatype-jsr310` module to `Jackson`.